# ubuntu: "File System" free space: 75.0 MB ?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space

I just installed Ubuntu side by side with XP on my laptop.

I'm trying to find how much free space I have left after installation.

I go into "**File Browser**" and click on "**File System**" in the left navigation panel.

It says:

```
22 items, Free Space: 75.0 MB
```

Whoa!

Really?

How can I check that this is correct?

If this is correct, then I probably need to wipe XP and install Ubuntu as the only operating system on this disk (the disk is only 80GB).

UPDATE:

`fdisk -l` says nothing

`df -h` says:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             2.3G  2.2G   71M  97% /
tmpfs                1003M     0 1003M   0% /lib/init/rw
varrun               1003M  108K 1002M   1% /var/run
varlock              1003M     0 1003M   0% /var/lock
udev                 1003M  176K 1002M   1% /dev
tmpfs                1003M   76K 1003M   1% /dev/shm
lrm                  1003M  2.4M 1000M   1% /lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/volatile
```

Comment: Sounds like your partitions were not set up correctly.  You may need to sudo fdisk -l to see the partition data.

Comment: Were you expecting your root drive to be larger then 2.3G? It is in fact almost full.

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, give the output of following commands:

```
fdisk -l
```

and

```
df -h
```

so we can check that.

Comment: You don't have to wipe XP if you don't want to do that. Consider use GParted Live CD -> http://gparted.sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 0):

df -h seems to confirm this. From the Menu -> Applications \ Accessories \ Disk Usage Analyzer will let you see visually in detail what is using the space.

Answer (score 0):

2.3 GB is really a small amount of space for modern full linux distributions, particularly if you want a full KDE/Gnome, OpenOffice.org, firefox, etc.